# THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera

Tags: three.js, aframe

I'm new to Aframe. I just setup the project via npm install.

I'm getting a THREE.js error and I can't figure out where it's comming from.

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer.render: camera is not an instance of THREE.Camera
```

The only thing I have in my page is:

```
<a-scene></a-scene>
```

I see that the plugin are loaded in the console:

```
A-Frame Version: 0.2.0
three Version: ^0.76.1
WebVR Polyfill Version: borismus/webvr-polyfill#f45f87a
THREE.WebGLRenderer 76
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thank you.

Comment: can you post portion of your code where camera is initialized

Comment: I think `<a-scene></a-scene>` instanciate camera by default. After some test, I included the js inline in the `<head>` and it seems to be working fine. I think there's a conflict between three,js from aframe npm and other npm plugin I installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, put A-Frame script tag in the head.